# Calculate min, max and average from a mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, stored-procedures

I have to calculate Min, Max and Average values from a MongoDB collection and insert those values into another collection in the same DB.

It has to be done automatically each 15 min, 1 hour and 1 day.

I was wondering if I could use a JavaScript function stored in MongoDB but I don't know how to call that function automatically at a specific time ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: you can use setTimeout() function of js.

Answer (score 0):

For calculate use aggregation function: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

To call JavaScript function automatically at specific time
use trigger from a client machine (cron job or scheduler task) 
or [mongo-scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-scheduler)